# DisplayTag: Show header even when there's no data to diaply

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, displaytag

I am using the java displaytag library. I need to show the headers in the html page even if no-data is present. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the value of the property `basic.empty.showtable` to `true`. You may do it on a specific table instance, by using the `<display:setProperty>` tag inside the `<display:table>` tag, or you may set it globally for the whole web application by setting it in your displaytag.properties file.

Read http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/configuration.html to understand how it works, discover the other useful properties.